# Update table error with NULL and BLANK inside in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I want to create update to convert datetime nvarchar to datetime. But I have problems to convert because there are NULL and BLANK.

```
update copy_vw_work_in_progress_so_list
Set ScanDateSO = CAST(FORMAT(cast([date_scan_so] as bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##') as datetime)
```

Can you guys help me ?
I am using SQL SERVER 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know what values you want the null and blank to take on, then you could use a case expression (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)

Something like this:

```
UPDATE copy_vw_work_in_progress_so_list SET ScanDateSO = 
  CASE 
     WHEN [date_scan_so] = ' ' THEN NULL
     WHEN [date_scan_so] IS NULL THEN NULL
     ELSE 
       CAST(FORMAT(CAST([date_scan_so] AS bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##') AS datetime)
  END
```

Comment: I get error, Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
..how do I know what is the problem, it could be not only NULL

Comment: the conversion fails if the string isn't in the expected date/time format -- so you'd want to look at the value you have in the string, and see where it doesn't match up to the format you've requested in the cast (or the default format, if you are relying on defaults)

Answer (score 0):

Add a where lenght [date_scan_so] is >0

```
update copy_vw_work_in_progress_so_list
Set ScanDateSO = CAST(FORMAT(cast([date_scan_so] as bigint),'####-##-## ##:##:##') 
as datetime)
Where Len[date_scan_so]>0
```

Comment: I get error Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string. Do u know why